# Socket connection in Web service spanning multiple requests

Tags: web-services, sockets

I have a Web service that is consumed by clients.  That Web service will communicate with another service via TCP.  Within the Web service, I want to establish and maintain a socket connection such that calls to the Web service will reuse that socket connection.

Unfortunately, I can't find any information about this technique so I don't know the pros and cons.  Is this a known pattern or anti-pattern?  What is it called?

I found information on "keep-alive" but I believe this pattern refers to the Web service client keeping the connection open over multiple requests.  I'm not sure if this is the same since my service is the client in this scenario and it is a TCP connection.